# Is it possible to auto-target in MW2 multi-player?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

In single player campaigns, you get an auto-target assist thingy when you press L1 on the PS Controller. Is there also something like that in multiplayer ?

I am a bit of a noob, and am getting royally pwnd by so many other faster players who can target me accurately. I have tried to customise the sensitivity of the controller, but just can't easily zero in on targets quickly. I know that latency (ie Ping) is not an issue.

Any player advice on this ?

Comment: I believe that disabling auto-aim is an intentional design feature, implemented in order to sort of allow skill to come into play more and be more of an advantage; that is, there would be an incentive to practice aiming and reflexive skills.

Comment: fair enough.. but i am just getting royally rogered on all the maps... Shame you can't run maps according to current level, rather than have a level 8 vs level 70 who just runs around pwning players left and right...LOL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's impossible to get the **same** auto-aim feature in multiplayer (unless you hack I guess), but there is a slight auto-aim. When you're ADS (Aiming Down Sight), and an enemy runs really close to your sight, it'll move it. This is really annoying when you're sniping and another enemy crosses your sight.

Also, I haven't tested, but word on the street is that some holographic sights have more auto-aim than red dot sights.

Comment: Is this on all platforms? Does this slight auto aim help those people run and snipe people before their sight is even up?

Answer (score 1):

The "Effect" people are referring to is called Aim Assist in multiplayer. While you cannot "auto-target" the same way you do in the campaign, when you are looking down the sight in multiplayer with Aim Assist enabled, and an enemy runs across where the crosshairs are aimed the gun gets "dragged" in the direction that the enemy ran. This is supposed to be as if your character "noticed" the enemy and the mind acts faster than the hands so your character "subconsciously" begins aiming at it.

This feature can be good and bad. Good in the sense that it gives you a bit of a one-up on the enemy if you walk around aiming down the sight, but bad in the sense that if one enemy is standing still and you are shooting at him, and another enemy runs between you and the enemy you are shooting at your gun often gets "dragged" off of the enemy you were shooting at, but doesn't snap to the new target fully. This can result in 2 enemies getting notified of your presence and while you are trying to reacquire your original target he has already had the time to turn, fire two shots, and kill you.

Aim Assist can be enabled or disabled in the in-game options menu in multiplayer.

Pros do not use Aim Assist. Even if you don't play the game professionally, if you have gotten through to level 70 you should turn Aim Assist off. Anyone in prestige mode should not be using aim assist either.

Answer (score -2):

Yes the auto-target / quick draw / scope "thingy" is in multiplayer and the mechanics are like single player campaign but the affect is different.

Comment: How do you enable the auto-target ???

Comment: As per luc M's comment above... Is that enabled through options, or do i have to "earn it" after a few levels. Just doesn't seem to be enabled by default. Can you elaborate a bit more please. Then, I can tick it as the answer and "+1" it to...Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't need to enable it. It just should work as it does in SP. Having said that, I thought it was a bit less sensitive than the SP equivalent. That is, I felt like I needed to have my crosshair closer to the target before it would snap-in.

Comment: I remember I de-activated it to get better without it when I began a campaign. When I started to play online, I didn't reactivate the auto-target. So, you tell me taht if I enable it, the auto-target will work when I play online ?

Comment: @Luc M, yes it you enable it it will work when you play online

Comment: @Elpezmuert Oh man!! I'll maybe able to get higher killstreak! I try it when back home. Thanks!

Comment: Not true, multiplayer auto aim IS NOT like single player auto aim

Comment: @Carlo, the mechanics are the same...I updated the answer to reflect this clarification

Comment: so I am still unsure now. So, it can be turned on/off in the settings, but if it is on, then it works but with reduced capability than in SP mode. That is to say, you need to manually target your opponent a bit more accurately before it kicks in ?

Comment: Carlo's answer explains the differences.

Comment: -1.. Answer was worse than my question...LOL

Comment: @MMO-Tragic, that wasn't very constructive